# How do I get the height of a table/element as a variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have these set in `<fo:layout-master-set>`tag

```
<fo:region-body margin-top="5cm" margin-bottom="2cm"/>
<fo:region-before extent="5cm"/>
<fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
```

I have a table declared in `region-before`. This is to make it repeat across every page when generated in pdf. This table's height is dynamic but the number of rows (5) are fixed. Hence, my `margin-top` also needs to be a variable.

How do I get the final height of the table in `region-before`, put it in a variable and transfer it over to `region-body`'s margin-top?

Comment: How is this different from what you asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667429/xsl-fo-how-do-i-repeat-an-xsl-table-for-every-page?

Comment: Very. @TonyGraham in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667429/xsl-fo-how-do-i-repeat-an-xsl-table-for-every-page I asked for a way to repeat it in a region-body but here, I asked for a way to get the height of the table in region-before so that I can set the margin-top of region-body dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Looks like I've answered this question there, since you wanted to 'repeat the whole table in each page', and the most reliable way is to put it in the `fo:region-before`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the table itself into a table header of another table that has one cell which contains the body content of the whole page. The table in the header will repeat on every page